# ftp connects but files aren't visible browsing

Tags: troubleshooting, ftp, dreamweaver

If this should be on that other site, please don't shoot me, as I can't remember the name or the url.

I have an ftp account in Dreamweaver that connects to the remote site and appears to be uploading files as normal. But when I browse to the location I can't see any new files or changes to the index page. (I've uploaded index.php and connect.php). I'm getting a 404 page.

I suspect the host directory is wrong, but looking at the file tree, I can't see the folder I'm supposed to be using, so I'm uploading to the apparent site root.

Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from a ACTIVE FTP connectionto a PASV connection.